# Thunderbird Gmail imap does not immediately sync messages changed on another comp or mobile

Tags: sync, thunderbird, imap

This happens often in thunderbird and I do not know how to solve it.

I open thunderbird on one pc and sync inbox with gmail. then I do to laptop and open the same gmail imap in Thunderbird. I read some messages and tag some message as important. When I return to my pc, Thunderbird did not sync gmail inbox. messages still remain undread and untagged. The same happens if I read gmail messages via my mobile phone.

What setting in my desktop thunderbird are wrong so that it does not properly or immediately sync gmail inbox? How can I force syncing of gmail inbox? Pressing `Get Mail -> accountName` does not sync imap gmail inbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imap fetches data at regular intervals. If you want it more immediate you might be able to make use of google's activesync exchange server. I dont know if thunderbird has that abil